# JS Script HTTP Request not firing or simply not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a website page in which a button fires an HTTP Request which makes a discord webhook send a message, but it is simply not working, does anyone know why this issue would be caused? no errors.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>cHECKEN BOT</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
        <script>
            function send() {
                const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("POST", "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/676118118082281513/ZS5YcWhurzokBrKX9NgexqtxrJA5Pu2Bo4i7_JsIxC-JIbPBVhSZkcVVukGOro52rnQA");
                request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
                const params = {
                    username: "bruh",
                    avatar_url: "",
                    content: document.getElementById("content").value
                }
                request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
            }
        </script>          
        <style>
            center {
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
            footer {
                position: absolute;
                width: 99%;
                bottom: 35px;
                text-align: center;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            talk to Q.U.A.C.K
            <br><input type="text" id="content">           
            <form onsubmit="return send();">
                <input type="submit" value="send">
            </form>
        </center>
        <footer><b><a href="/">home</a></b></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `send()` should return `false`. Otherwise submitting the form will reload the page.

Comment: Ah okay, I will try that.

Comment: Just try using a fetch request instead plain old XMLHTTPRequest ... It would be much cleaner . Moreover I think you need to pass your cookies or some other credentials to get access ...

Comment: Also use `e.preventDefault` method to prevent the default action of the form !